# method in class cannot be applied - returning double value from method

Tags: java

Can't seem to find a specific instance of this issue with search. Then again, I am new to the site. There are still several steps to this problem, but I can't even get the results of the method calculation to display. All I want to do is display the results of the method "calcAverage". As the code is currently written, it returns the error. I'm reading the book and the assignment instructions over and over and I know the answer is staring me straight in the face. Thanks in advance to anyone who can provide advice:

> Grades.java:13: error: method calcAverage 
>   in class Grades cannot be applied to given types;

```
  calcAverage();
  ^
```

> required: int,int,int,int,int
>
> found: no arguments
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
   public class Grades
   {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

       int score1,  score2, score3, score4, score5;
       double average;

       calcAverage();

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter the " 
                          + "first score:");
       score1 = input.nextInt();


       System.out.println("Enter the " 
                          + "second score:");
       score2 = input.nextInt();


       System.out.println("Enter the " 
                          + "third score:");
       score3 = input.nextInt();


       System.out.println("Enter the " 
                          + "fourth score:");
       score4 = input.nextInt();


       System.out.println("Enter the " 
                          + "fifth score:");
       score5 = input.nextInt();
    }



public double calcAverage(int   score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5)
    {    
        return ((score1 +   score2 +    score3 +    score4 +    score5) / 5);
    }
```

}

Comment: Watch out for the integer division.  Your method is always going to return a whole number, even though you've declared it as `double`.  If that's not what you want, change `5` to `5.0` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is obvious, your method `calcAverage()` excepects 5 integer arguments and you're not passing any arguments to it. Pass a 5 arguments and it would compile fine. To display the results, just wrap the method call like this:

```
System.out.println(calcAverage(1,1,1,1,1)); // Replace 1 with your actual value.
```

Comment: tried adding this after inputs recieved and get:

Grades.java:39: error: non-static method calcAverage(int,int,int,int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: changing the method to static solved the problem. thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Your calcAverage method needs 5 arguments:

```
double calcAverage(int   score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5)
```

And you provide no arguments when you call it:

```
calcAverage();
```

You should instead call:

```
calcAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look no further error clearly states

> Grades.java:13: error: method calcAverage in class Grades cannot be applied to given types;

The method you are calling in incompatible with the method definition that exists. So either define a method that has same signature as the method you are calling or call the method which already exists.

So you need to call

```
calcAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)
```

after you take all inputs.